# Add line legend to geom_sf

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, r-sf

I have a couple spatial shape files with various public transport routes and I would like to make a map using `ggplot2` and `sf` libraries. The issue here is that I manually assign colors to a few specific routes but I couldn't manage to add a legend to the plot.

Any idea on how to do this using `geom_sf` ?

**Reproducible example**

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# reproducible data
  lon<-c(5.121420, 6.566502, 4.895168, 7.626135)
  lat<-c(52.09074, 53.21938, 52.37022, 51.96066)
  cities<-c('utrecht','groningen','amsterdam','munster')
  size<-c(300,500,1000,50)

  xy.cities<-data.frame(lon,lat,cities,size)

  # line example
  line1 <- st_linestring(as.matrix(xy.cities[1:2,1:2]))
  line2 <- st_linestring(as.matrix(xy.cities[3:4,1:2]))

  lines.sfc <- st_sfc(list(line1,line2))
  simple.lines.sf <- st_sf(id=1:2,size=c(10,50),geometry=lines.sfc)

# plot
  ggplot() + 
    geom_sf(data= subset(simple.lines.sf, id==1), color="red" ) +
    geom_sf(data= subset(simple.lines.sf, id==2), color="blue" )
```

[image]

I know it would be possible to do something like this:

```
  ggplot() + 
    geom_sf(data= subset(simple.lines.sf, id>0), aes(color=factor(id)) ) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue"), 
                       labels=c("route 1", "route 2"))
```

[image]

However, I'm working with more than one shape file so I need to use more than one `geom_sf`. Also, I would like the legend to look a line legend, not a polygon legend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use the argument `show.legend` from `geom_sf` here.

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_sf(data= simple.lines.sf, aes(colour = as.factor(id)), show.legend = "line")
```

Description of `show.legend` from `?geom_sf`

> logical. Should this layer be included in the legends? NA, the default, includes if any aesthetics are mapped. FALSE never includes, and TRUE always includes.
>   You can also set this to one of "polygon", "line", and "point" to override the default legend.