# Add multiple legends to ggplot2 when using geom_sf

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend, r-sf

My question combines two separate issues posted on before on Stackoverflow: i.  [Adding multiple legends to ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443371/adding-multiple-legends-to-ggplot) and ii. [Add line legend to geom_sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996634/add-line-legend-to-geom-sf).

I would like to add multiple legends to `ggplot2` (as in the first post), but am using `sf`. This complicates filling up the aesthetic space. The answer suggested in i. above does not work well with multiple types of geometries -- we cannot assign points and lines to a single class and then use factors. In my case, I have several line and point shapefiles, and simply want to add a separate legend entry for each shapefile added.

There seems to be no need to invoke `aes()`, but `aes()` may be the only way to call a legend.

**Reproducible example**

I would like to do something similar to the following (borrowing from (i)), but ***without*** the `as.factor` so that I could have separate calls of `geom_sf`:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# reproducible data
lon<-c(5.121420, 6.566502, 4.895168, 7.626135)
lat<-c(52.09074, 53.21938, 52.37022, 51.96066)
cities<-c('utrecht','groningen','amsterdam','munster')
size<-c(300,500,1000,50)

xy.cities<-data.frame(lon,lat,cities,size)

# line example
line1 <- st_linestring(as.matrix(xy.cities[1:2,1:2]))
line2 <- st_linestring(as.matrix(xy.cities[3:4,1:2]))

lines.sfc <- st_sfc(list(line1,line2))
simple.lines.sf <- st_sf(id=1:2,size=c(10,50),geometry=lines.sfc)

ggplot() + 
 geom_sf(data= simple.lines.sf, aes(colour = as.factor(id)), show.legend = "line")
```

That is, something more like:

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_sf(data= dataset1, color="red" ) +
 geom_sf(data= dataset2, color="blue" )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain that I understand exactly what you want. 
Here we map values "A" and "B" to the color aestetic in order to obtain a legend and then we customize the colors with `scale_color_manual`

```
dataset1 <- st_sf(st_sfc(list(line1)))
dataset2 <- st_sf(st_sfc(list(line2)))

ggplot() + 
    geom_sf(data= dataset1, aes(color="A"), show.legend = "line") +
    geom_sf(data= dataset2, aes(color="B"), show.legend = "line") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue"), 
                       labels = c("Line1", "Line2"),
                       name = "Which line ?")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is precisely what I wanted -- to be able to force an aesthetic and then call it later. I didn't realized you could force a constant like that: "A" and "B".

Comment: If anyone else comes across this with a similar issues and is then trying to figure out how to combine legends, here are some useful links: [Combine legends for color and shape into a single legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410908/combine-legends-for-color-and-shape-into-a-single-legend)

Comment: Although, now I get the following error: `Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE` which seems to be coming from invoking `show.legend = "line"` -- if I exclude `show.legend` there's no problem, except that the legend figure is a fill not a line.

Comment: I don't have any error message with the provided code, `ggplot2_2.2.1.9000` and `sf_0.5-4`...

Comment: Ok -- after restart I didn't either. Thanks!