# Size legend of sf object won't show correct symbols

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, geospatial, r-sf

Does anyone know why the legend of the `size` aestatic `BIR74` won't show the dot sizes but rectangles? If the answer is yes, how can I fix this?

Reproducable example:

```
library(sf)
# devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

nc_centers <- st_centroid(nc)

nc_centers %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(color = SID79, size = BIR74)) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: No sample data means few people will be able to play with your sample code. There exists a [related and known issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2037) that was closed on 1 November 2017. Have you tried updating `ggplot2`?

Comment: The example HAS sample data. Thanks I'll try update it.

Comment: Does the same for me with sf:0.6.1 and ggplot2:2.2.1.9000 (which is older than the bug report...)

Comment: Still fails with the github version via devtools. With just the `size` aesthetic you get wrong legend objects. `ggplot(nc_centers, aes(size=BIR74)) + geom_sf()` Solution? Use `tmap` instead?

Comment: You're right on the all accounts; I can confirm the issue. I suggest leaving a comment at the respective [`sf`](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/88) or [`ggplot2`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2037) GitHub issues.

Comment: this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996634/add-line-legend-to-geom-sf?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need to add the show.legend argument to geom_sf, i.e.

```
nc_centers %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(color = SID79, size = BIR74), show.legend = 'point') +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]