# How to specify shape for color legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am plotting spatial point data (`sf`) with `ggplot2`. Color is mapped to an associated value. The legend for color is unexpectedly using a polygon shape as it would for a two-dimensional geom that might have separate color and fill attributes. Is there a way to specify that the shape for the color legend so that I can make it a filled circle?

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(10, min = 0, max = 10),
                 y = runif(10, min = 0, max = 10),
                 value = sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), 10, replace = TRUE))
sf <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("x", "y"))

ggplot(sf, aes(color=value)) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add line legend to geom\_sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996634/add-line-legend-to-geom-sf)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is as below:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = sf, aes(color=value), show.legend = "point") 
# you can also choose "line" for instance
```

[image]

Comment: Now why did I not see that in the documentation for `geom_sf`. I think I just expected `show.legend` to take a logical argument.

Comment: Usually it does only take a logical argument. For `geom_sf`, this is an issue still https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/881